# No component found to process as 'ajaxSingle'

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Found strange problem, possibly bug.

I have 2 identical web-pages with Richfaces:suggestionbox.

On the first one my suggestionBox is doing well, everything works fine, but on another one i have some problems. SuggestionBox doesn't show my suggestions. In logs i have something like this:

```
WARNING: No component found to process as 'ajaxSingle' for clientId remains-form:konta-suggest
2010.1.9 12:02:29 org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot processPhase
```

Any conclusions?

**UPD:**

```
    <h:inputText value="#{repobean.kont}" id="kont" label="Payer" style="width:230px;"/>
    <rich:suggestionbox onobjectchange="printObjectsSelected(#{rich:element('konta-id')}, #{rich:component('konta-suggest')}, 'id');" usingSuggestObjects="true" width="230" var="result" fetchValue="#{result.kont}" suggestionAction="#{kontabean.suggest}" id="konta-suggest" for="kont">
                                    <h:column>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{result.kont}"/>
                                    </h:column>
                                    <h:column>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{result.kontName}"/>
                                    </h:column>
                                </rich:suggestionbox>
<h:inputHidden id="konta-id" value="#{repobean.kontId}" />
```

Javascript inside onobjectchange is a function which prints id into konta-id.

The code of jsp on the second page is copy-pasted from the first page.

Comment: Would love to see the code...  Given the error, check your ids.

Comment: Where in your code is `ajaxSingle`?

Comment: ajaxSingle was in rich:suggestionBox, but i removed it due to debugging process. If i remove ajaxSingle in the first page, where everything works, it still works fine. =[

Answer (score 2):

I know, the question is 5 years old, but we had this same error (with different components)

In our case we have changed the outer `ui:repeat` to an `a4j:repeat`.
After that, our components worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, when you encounter Ajax problems, is to add the [`<a4j:log>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/log.jsf) component:

```
<a4j:log popup="false"/>
```

This will create a box in your page with all the Ajax logs from Richfaces. Eventually, you can set `popup="true"` and then display the popup by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

There are many logs in this panel, but generally the important things to look at is the WARN or ERROR messages.

Other concern about your error message: it is talking about some `ajaxSingle` processing. In your JSF code, you have no `ajaxSingle` attribute defined. When does this error happens? When you start typing some characters in your `inputText` component?

Comment: Yes, error happens, when i start to input characters in inputText.

Comment: @Yurish Did you get interesting information with the `<a4j:log/>` component?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there any conditional rendering (`rendered="#{some expression}"`) around this input and suggestion components? Or an iteration?

Does `.suggest()` action get invoked before this error?

Situations like you've described happen when an action-related (causing) component is within a conditional render (or an iteration) which does not allow a component to be created on RestoreView phase. Then action is not called at all and component-id is not found in the component tree.

Example: if you have something like this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty myBean.valueSetInActionHandler}">
  <h:commandLink id="action1" action="#{myBean.callOtherAction" value="appears after action"/>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:commandLink id="action2" action="#{myBean.setValueInActionHandler}" value="display button above"/>
```

First render - only one, second button is rendered. If `setValueInActionHandler` sets some value and displays the same page - first button ("appears after action") will get rendered too. But clicking it won't fire a `callOtherAction` - because on second request, during RestorePhase  valueInActionHandler is empty again, so action1 will not be available...

Hope I managed to make myself clear :)

Answer (score -2):

I think a4j taglib is missing on the page.